# why does the first code is unable of storing the sum in a char, but the second stores it; whats going on when i scan the values that is different?

Tags: c, char, scanf, undefined-behavior, conversion-specifier

I have this working code that assigns fixed values to some `unsigned char` variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main2() 

{   
 unsigned char a,b;
    a=1,b=2;
    a=(a+b)/2;
    printf("\nAverage: %d\n%18d",a,sizeof(a));  

return 0;
}
```

But when I try reading in the values instead, like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main() 

{   
 unsigned char a,b;
    scanf(" %d", &a);   scanf(" %d", &b);
    a=a,
    b=b,
    a=(a+b)/2;
    printf("\nAverage: %d\n%18d",a,sizeof(a));  

return 0;
}
```

it doesn't work. Why not? It seems that `scanf` takes only the last value when I print the sum.

This is my best attempt to fix the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
unsigned char b;
unsigned short int a;
    scanf(" %u", &a);
    scanf(" %u", &b);
    b=b;{

    b=(a+b);
unsigned short int a;
    scanf(" %u", &a);{  
    
    
    b=(a+b)/3;
    printf("\nAverage: %u",b);  
    printf("\n   sizeof: %d",sizeof(b));
    
    
    }
            
}
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `scanf` with `%d` or `%u` will fill 32-bit value. Which means UB - you give it pointer to 8-bit. Next 3 bytes will be damaged.

Comment: What do you think the assignments `a=a` and `b=b` will do? Why are you using the comma-operator? If you want to do separate statements, use actual statements with the statement terminator `;`.

Comment: As for your problem, perhaps [a good `scanf` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might help? The `%u` format is for an `unsigned int` argument. And never forget to check what `scanf` (and related functions) actually returns.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "i know the a unsigned char is able to store at most 255, but im ok with that range" - in your own words, where the code says `scanf(" %d", &a);`, exactly what do you think the `%d` part means? How are you expecting `scanf` to *know about* the size limit on `a`? And *why* are you restricting the variable size like this, when it is easier to type `int`? (If your answer is "to save memory", then this is misguided in **several** ways.)

Comment: @Luca Fiorentino Heredia, "This is my best attempt to fix the code:" --> why `b=(a+b)/3;` instead of `b=(a+b)/2;`?

Comment: This is the 3rd "wrong format specifier in printf/scanf" today. We need a canonical duplicate for closing these. They are also evidently of no use for future readers since the same FAQ keeps getting asked over and over.

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function)

> 13 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.

And you are using invalid conversion specifiers with declared objects as for example:

```
unsigned char a,b;
scanf(" %d", &a);   scanf(" %d", &b);
```

The conversion specifier d is designed to deal with objects of the type `int` not with objects of the type `unsigned char`.

Instead you need to write:

```
unsigned char a,b;
scanf(" %hhu", &a);   scanf(" %hhu", &b);
```

or instead of:

```
unsigned short int a;
scanf(" %u", &a);{
```

you need to write:

```
unsigned short int a;
scanf(" %hu", &a);{
```

Also the `sizeof` operator returns values of the type `size_t`. So to output such values you need to use the conversion specifier `zu` instead of `d`:

```
printf("\nAverage: %d\n%18zu\n",a,sizeof(a));
```

or for example:

```
printf("\n   sizeof: %zu\n",sizeof(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

General advice: take warnings to heart when compiling. Copying and pasting your code gave me the following:

> main.c:8:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘unsigned char *’ [-Wformat=]
> 8 |     scanf(" %d", &a);

So taking all warning into account, I can re-order your first program to this (which works!):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    scanf(" %d", &a);
    scanf(" %d", &b);
    // a = a, --> has no effect
    // b = b, --> has no effect
    a = (a + b) / 2;
    printf("\nAverage: %d\n%18d", a, sizeof(a));
    return 0;
}
```

If you really do want to use unsigned chars, go with %hhu:

```
unsigned char a, b;
scanf(" %hhu", &a);
scanf(" %hhu", &b);
```

Comment: Remember that `sizeof` returns a value of type `size_t` which needs the `%zu` format specifier.